# Как правильно написать предложение?1

Tags: окончания

***Я с классом и учителем ходил в театр*** или
***Я с классом и учителем ходили в театр***, или
***Мы с классом и учителем ходили в театр?***

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Я с классом и учителем ходил в театр. Сказуемое в этом примере должно согласоваться с подлежащим "Я", чем и обусловлен выбор ед. ч.

Или: **Мы с классом и учителем ходили в театр.** В этом предложении форма множественного числа сказуемого показывает, что в роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание, т. е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам.

См.: [Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию. Д.Э Розенталь. М.: ЧеРо, 1999.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)